# Gather data from one data frame to another according to column names and factors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, lapply

I need to gather some data from one dataset to another one.

I made this example to make it simpler:

Dataset 1:

```
ID_marquesina<-c("1","1","1","2","2")
profile<-c("Good","Bad","Good","Normal","Bad")
Vis_profile<-c("10","20","30","5","0")

Vis_marquesina_profile<-data.frame(ID_marquesina,profile,Vis_profile)
```

Dataset 2:

```
ID<-c("1","2","3","4")
Good<-NA
Bad<-NA
Normal<-NA
Dataset_Marquesinas<-data.frame(ID,Good,Bad,Normal)
```

As it can be seen in the first dataset there is a variable called profile ("Good","Bad","Normal") which are the column names in the second dataset.

Also there is the ID in both datasets, where some ID "1", "2" are present in both datasets and others no.

WHat I need to do is :

Fill the dataset 2 with the data from dataset 1. So for example if in dataset 1 ID_marquesina = 1 and profile = "Good". take the Vis_profile (10) and put it in the dataset 2 with ID= 1 and column = Good.

I tried lapply function and some for loops with if but I couldnt make it work !!!

Any advice would be really appreciated !!

Thanks !!

Comment: Please post example of wanted answer. Why `ID = 1` has two `Good` (`10` and `30`)?

Comment: As @PoGibas mentioned you have two values for grouping variable and all the 'Vis_profile' is a `factor` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by `spread`ing the first dataset and bind it with the second dataset to fill in the values

```
library(dplyr)
Vis_marquesina_profile %>% 
    group_by(ID = ID_marquesina, profile) %>%
    summarise(Vis_profile = mean(Vis_profile)) %>%
    spread(profile, Vis_profile) %>% 
    bind_rows(Dataset_Marquesinas) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

Another option is to change the 'ID_marquesina' to `factor` by changing the `levels` to include the levels of the 'ID' column from second dataset

```
Vis_marquesina_profile %>% 
   group_by(ID = factor(ID_marquesina, levels = Dataset_Marquesinas$ID), 
            profile) %>% 
   summarise(Vis_profile = mean(Vis_profile)) %>%
   spread(profile, Vis_profile, drop = FALSE)
```

NOTE: There are multiple 'Vis_profile' values for each group ('ID_marquesina', 'profile') and it is not clear whether we need to take the `mean` or `sum` or `max` etc (the column is `factor`, changed it to `numeric`)

Comment: Doubt that OP wants to fill with `0` as he provides `0` as one of the numbers of the `Vis_marquesina_profile`